# Is it possible to combine two Mongodb queries?

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Actually I have two date ranges, one is actual date range and the other is comparison date range. For each date range I'm executing two different queries.

I selected aggregation method. Code I wrote for each date range is ..

```
$resultsetpre = $db_1->command(array(
    'aggregate' => 'ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE',
    'pipeline'  => array(
        array(
            '$match' => array('Date' => array('$gte'=>$actualstartdate,'$lte'=>$actualenddate))
        ),
        array('$group'  => array(
            '_id'       => "$Id",
            'Clicks'  => array('$sum' => '$Clicks'),
            'Impressions' => array('$sum' => '$Impressions'),
            'Cost' => array('$sum' => '$Cost'),
            'Conversions' => array('$sum' => '$Conversions'),
        ))
    ),
));
```

My doubt is can I write a query, so that gets data for both date ranges in diff columns. Since I had too many of records it is taking long time.

I'm very thankful If any one help me out from this. Thanks In Advance.

Comment: No this is not possible to do with one query I believe, plus I don't think it will help. Index optimsation (if not done) will help or if failing that you are simply trying to $group something huge as such you should look into shrinking the workload on your database by pre-aggregation etc

Comment: Yeah, I can try in group but the problem is it doesn't allow more than 10000 unique keys right?

Comment: Ok, Can you say how to work it in group.

Comment: Why doesn't it allow more than 10,000 unique keys?

Comment: You can use `$or` in a `$match` to effectively merge the results of two queries.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: No Johnny, Actually I need Sum of Clicks for actual date range in Clicks Column and sum of comparision date range clicks in CompClicks.

Comment: Sammaye, yeah. I tried first group it self.

Comment: You can do this in aggregation, see my answer.  And don't use the old 'group' for anything, that's basically useless and left over from the old pre-aggregation days.

Comment: @Sammaye can you explain how to get it in group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to compare the number of clicks (or some other sum) for two different date ranges.  Think of it as doing an aggregation by days.  Instead of days you will translate your date into range1, range2 or other and the group by those values.

Here's an example to get you started that compares two date ranges, start1-end1, start2-end2:

```
project = { "$project" : { 
             "clicks" : 1,
             "range"  : { "$cond" : [ { "$and" : [ 
                                                  { "$gt":["$Date",start1] },
                                                  { "$lt":["$Date",end1] }
                                               ]
                                      },
                                      "range1",
                                      { "$cond" : [ { "$and" : [
                                                          { "$gt":["$Date",start2] },
                                                          { "$lt":["$Date",end2] }
                                                               ]
                                                     },
                                                     "range2",
                                                     null
                                                  ]
                                      }
                                    ]
                        }
             }
};

group = { "$group" : { "_id" : "$range",
                       "clicks" : { "$sum" : "$clicks" }
        }
};
```

Now running `db.collection.aggregate( project, group )` will give you sum of clicks for each of the two date ranges.  You can `$match` as the middle step to remove `{range:null}` to get rid of documents that didn't match your two ranges.

You mentioned that you have an "Id" field in the original documents you want to aggregate by, so all you need to do is add "Id":1, to the `$project` step and then change the grouping clause in the `$group` as follows:

```
group = { "$group" : { "_id" : {"Id" : "$Id", "range" : "$range"},
                       "clicks" : { "$sum" : "$clicks" }
        }
};
```

Instead of grouping by date ranges across the whole collection, this will group by Id,range so that for each Id you get a sum for range1 and a sum for range2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me try once.

Comment: I tried this ans. But my new problem is there is unique constraint Id. I need to get clicks for each Id. I forgot to represent there.

Comment: you can aggregate by id and range.  I'll add a note to my answer.

Comment: Yeah I'm getting the correct out put. Can we get values in same document? Like below.(Check what I posted in ans)

Comment: I tried this in group. But Group allows only 20000 unique key values. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.group/  Array
(
    [retval] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Id] => 17855692
                    [Clicks] => 131
                    [Impressions] => 32319
                    [Conversions] => 2
                    [Cost] => 113.35000011325
                    [ClicksC] => 0
                    [ImpressionsC] => 0
                    [ConversionsC] => 0
                    [CostC] => 0
                )
 )
)

Comment: that's old map-reduce group - it has nothing to do with aggregation framework.

Answer (score 0):

May be I am missing something, but what is the problem with combining them in the following way:

```
'$match' => array(
   'Date' => array('$gte'=>$actualstartdate,'$lte'=>$actualenddate),
    // here is your another query
)
```

If I am missing the point, please post both queries you are performing.

If you need to combine two the same queries, you can do this with [$or](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)

```
$match' => array(
   '$or' => array(
      'Date' => array('$gte'=>$actualstartdate1,'$lte'=>$actualenddate1),
      'Date' => array('$gte'=>$actualstartdate2,'$lte'=>$actualenddate2),
   )
)
```

Comment: Same query with diff date ranges.

Comment: you are missing the point - the question is how to get sums for each of the ranges.

Comment: Salvador Dali, Can you see the above answer and comments.